# Making parent level links clickable in Bootstrap and WordPress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, navigation, clickable

I'd like the top level menu items (that you mouse over to get the dropdowns to appear) to be clickable. Meaning that, when you click on them they go to a webpage instead of only making the dropdown appear.

I've found a bunch of solutions that don't work for me, probably because I copied a bunch of custom code from the internet in order to try to make the dropdown appear on hover and fade in - I'm a relative newbie. (If there's a better way of making the dropdown fade in I'm all ears). Also, easy solutions like stripping out classes, data-toggle, etc, don't seem to be working for me since I built a custom theme in WP. I could be not using them correctly.

Also I'm fine with dropdowns working not working on mobile devices, I'm not using them on mobiles.

Thanks!

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu{
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;

    -moz-transition:    all 1000ms ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1000ms ease;
    -o-transition:      all 1000ms ease;
    -ms-transition:     all 1000ms ease;
    transition:         all 1000ms ease;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}

.caret {
  display: none;
}

.navbar-default {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover {
  background: rgba (0,0,0,0);
  color: #ffffff;
}

.nav > li {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;  
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:after {
  content:"\2588 \00a0 \00a0 \00a0 \00a0 \2588 \00a0 \00a0 \00a0 \00a0 \2588";
  color: #f7981b;
  font-size: 1px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-indent: -10px;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-opacity: 0.25;
  -moz-opacity: 0.25;
  opacity: 0.25;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover:after {
  content:"\2588 \00a0 \00a0 \00a0 \00a0 \2588 \00a0 \00a0 \00a0 \00a0 \2588";
  font-size: 10px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-indent: -10px;
  display: block;
  color: #f7981b;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}


.nav > li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0px;
  background: rgba(61,33,15,0.8);
  list-style: none;
}

.nav > li > ul > li {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.nav > li > ul > li:hover {
  background-color: #f7981b;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}


.nav > li > ul > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #f7981b;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  text-align: center;
}

.nav > li > ul > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0,);
}

.nav > li > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  white-space: normal;
} 

.dropdown {
  text-align:center;
}

.dropdown-menu > .active > a, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.button, .dropdown-menu {
  margin:0px auto
}

.dropdown-menu {
  width:180px; 
  left:50%; 
  margin-left:-85px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0)!important;
  color: #ffffff!important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}



<div class="flex-container brown-80 hcenter">
            <div class="container-1300 pad-10 vcenter hcenter-nav">
              <div class="navbar-header brown-80">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" style="position: absolute; margin-left: -50px;">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-1300 pad-10 vcenter hcenter-lg flex-container">
          <div class="flex-10-percent hcenter">
              <a href="/" class="logo-bg"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-90-percent vcenter hcenter">
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse fright-lg" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <?php
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'menu'              => 'header-menu',
                        'theme_location'    => 'header-menu',
                        'depth'             => 3,
                        'container'         => false,
                        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                        'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                        'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                    );
                ?>

              </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
           </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix. In my wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php file, I changed this:

```
 // If item has_children add atts to a.
if ( $args->has_children && $depth === 0 ) {
   $atts['href']        = '#';
   $atts['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
   $atts['class']           = 'dropdown-toggle';
} else {
   $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
}
```

to this:

```
// If item has_children add atts to a.
if ( $args->has_children && $depth === 0 ) {
   $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
   //$atts['data-toggle']   = 'dropdown';
   $atts['class']           = 'dropdown-toggle';
} else {
   $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
}
```

Comment: How did you fix on mobiles because this fix doesn't go well with them?

Comment: I didn't need the drop downs to even appear on mobile devices so this fix worked for me.

Basically, each drop-down secondary page was accessible both through the top navigation and through a second navigation menu on each page. Redundant, but that's what the client requested. So, if on mobile devices the user couldn't see the drop down menu, they could go to the second navigation menu. It's an extra step, but worth it to not have the confusing link that can't be clicked on.

Comment: Ok, thanks for responding. In the end I decided to extend the navwalker class and beside parent link inside <li> I have placed a dropdown icon to toggle for its children. Works just fine

Comment: Great idea, I'm going to try that on my site - might be coming back with questions!